# UFT / QTP :: Unable to select/click SwfTab

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, uft14

In my application there is window which has 3 SwfTab tabs and hierarchy is

```
swfWindow().swfTab()
```

Above object exists and gets highlighted as well. I want to select any tab for which I tried below ways but it didn't select the tab

1. `obj.Select "ABC"`
2. Tried `ChildObjects` but got 0 items
3. Did recording but after rerun it didn't select any tab

So What are the other ways to select required swfTab?

I thought of `swfWindow().swfTab().Object`  but was not sure of method which can be used after `.Object`

How to get all possible options/methods after `.Object` method?